# Which particle do I use to express using a writing instrument?

Tags: particles, particle-で

"I'm writing **with** a pen"

"I'm writing **with** a pencil"

"I'm drawing **with** a blue crayon"

and so on.

> ボールペン**で**かいています。

or

> ボールペン**を**かいています。

or what do I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ボールペンで書{か}いています is correct で = "by means of/with" in this context.

Your other sentence ボールペンをかいています would literally mean "I am writing a pen" which doesn't make any sense.